# AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [] does not exist but it does

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-13.10

I need some help figuring why apache tells me that my document root does not exists.

My document root is `/home/user/Documents/Git/site/index.html`... It is there!

My vhost looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/Documents/Git/site/index.html
    ErrorLog /home/user/Documents/Git/site/error.log
    <Directory /home/user/Documents/Git/site>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Permissions are 775 for Git and its subfolders and files and in my hosts `127.0.1.1 site.com`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your document root cannot be a file, it must be a directory.

Comment: I logged in the first time for years, just to upvote this. You are my hero.

Answer (score 3):

Use below command to know where is the apache configure file is: then to update the document root:

```
# apache2ctl -S   [On Debian/Ubuntu]
# apachectl -S    [On CentOS/RHEL]
OR
# httpd -S
```

it shows below:

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/local/opt/httpd24/Users/YOURNAME/SOMESITE] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/local/opt/httpd24/c:/dev/blog] does not exist
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:80           blog.localhost (/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:29)
172.18.0.4:80          Somesite.localhost (/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:24)
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd24"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Users/YOURNAME/Sites"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="YOURNAME" id=501 not_used
Group: name="staff" id=20 not_used
```

In this case , you will know the warning, then update the Vhost file to delete the Vhosts.

```
   sudo nano /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

It works!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, document root can not be a file such as index.html.
Create a root like /var/www. Not like /var/www/index.html